# Qué método es mejor (en términos de rendimiento) para recuperar un fichero conocido con la clase ZipFile

Tags: java, rendimiento

Estoy tratando de mejorar el rendimiento de mi aplicación y, si alguien sabe en términos de rendimiento (benchmark) qué opción es mejor, por favor, ¿me lo podéis indicar?

Las opciones que estoy tratando de implementar son:

1.- Iterar las *entries* para encontrar el elemento buscado:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {

  ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
  if(zipEntry.getName().equals(file_name)) {
    doStuff();
    break;
  }

}
```

2.- Usar el método *getEntry* de la clase ZipFile:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(file_name);

if(zipEntry!=null) {
  doStuff();
}
```

PD: Si la pregunta no es válida, por favor, ¿podéis indicarme en qué falla?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: en tu heuristica ya tomaste en cuenta el promedio de archivos comprimidos que vas a procesar?

Comment: Hola Ruslan, los ficheros zip contienen unos 2.000 archivos.

Comment: Pues de ver tu código es evidente de que la alternativa 2 es por mucho mejor. En la alternativa 1 vas a iterar por cada uno de los entries n veces (donde n es la cantidad de archivos) ejecutando n comparaciones de más, mientras que en la alternativa 2 vas directamente al archivo que te interesa y haces lo que sea que necesitas. ¿No es evidente?

Comment: Eso supongo Jaime, la cuestión es saber si la iteración (punto 1) funciona mejor que el método getEntry de la clase, ya que se supone que internamente también debe buscar el archivo. La cuestión también es que no sé como medir el consumo de la cpu para comprobarlo

Comment: En eso tiene razón, pero dudo que su implementación interna sea más lenta que la búsqueda que propones. De cualquier forma, la única forma de saberlo es probándolo. En el peor caso, debe ser igual, en el mejor, usan alguna especie de búsqueda de bajo nivel o algún HashMap y la búsqueda es intantánea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En terminos de rendimiento siempre va a ser mejor la segunda opcion si usas alguna variante de Oracle, incluido el open jdk.

Esto debido a que es una [rutina nativa](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java#L320) y por lo tanto esta optimizada para la busqueda por nombre del archivo.

Si no tuvieras el nombre de archivo y tuvieras que procesar los elementos es mejor usar el metodo `stream()` que te permitira usar un spliterador para acceder a los elementos, con la ventaja de que si usas el stream API puedes tener muy facilmente procesamiento paralelo.

Comment: Gracias Ruslan, trataré de hacer mediciones de consumo de cpu para corroborarlo.